# ParseInt codebreak

Tags: javascript, parseint

Hi everyone I have a code problem that I'd like to see fixed:
here is my `else if` statement:

```
 var x = parseInt(2);
 var out = document.getElementById("output");

 var w = prompt("hunt or farm? dare to fight?");

 out.innerHTML = w;

 else if (w === "farm") {

     var farm = document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML;

     farm = parseInt(farm) + x;

     document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML = farm;
 }
```

Using divs in html I have linked  certain things to make a text base strategy game. but my problem is farm is NaN(not considered a number) I have placed "parseInt" to attempt to fix this problem but its still comes up with "NaN". what to I do to make sure instead of 2+2 = 22 make 2+2 = 4

Comment: Without `if`you can't have `else if`

Comment: yeah i know that , its just part of my code im using as an example

Comment: This isn't valid JS. What is the `else` connected to? What is the `farm` element? An `input`? Then you'll need to get its `value`, not its `innerHTML`.

Comment: what's inside `farm` could you share a sample input?

Comment: whether `farm` an input text box or some `div`? If it's a text box use `.value` instead and also before parseInt, check if `farm` is not undefined/null and then add

Comment: Why `var x = parseInt(2);`?  That could just be `var x = 2;`.

Answer (score 0):

```
try this hope its working for you


   var farm = document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML;

   farm = parseInt(farm + x);

   document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML = parseInt(farm);}
```

Comment: Unlikely to work, please try testing it. First, the `innerHTML` of `farm`, assuming it's an `input`, is going to be null. Adding `null` to anything and then doing `parseInt` of the result is not going to do anything useful.

Comment: Also i don't think `farm` is an `input` as the OP is using innerHTML for it instead of value

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that the element with the `farm` id's innerHTML starts with numbers, not letters. The same goes for the `x`. Additionally, they need to have at least one number. Try `parseInt("hello12345")` and you will get `NaN` as you did. The same will be for `parseInt("hello")`. Try adding NaN and a number and you'll still get `NaN`, like you are likely doing. `parseInt("hello12345hello") + parseInt("12345hello")` will return `NaN` However `parseInt("12345hello")` will return `12345`. This code will parse out the leading letters using regex `"hello12345".replace(/^(\D+)/, "")` will result in `12345`. However, you may want to check if there are any numbers to begin with before you use it because just letters will result in `NaN`. For more information about when the javascript `parseInt` function returns `NaN` look at the documentation https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Answer (score 0):

Looks like `farm` is a div/block element:

It's better to check if the value inside `farm` is valid after trimming it and also make sure it's valid number.

```
var farm = document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML.replace(/\s/gm,"");
    // trimming any empty spaces
    // checking for is it a valid number
    farm = farm!="" && !isNaN(farm)? parseInt(farm) + x : x;
    document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML = farm;
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/jabole/3/edit?html,js,output)**

In case `farm` is an input text box, just replace `innerHTML` with `value` and same code will work fine

Answer (score 0):

This works well for me, assuming I understand what you're trying to do. I'm passing `farm's` innerHTML to the `Number()` constructor. Alternatives would be to use `parseInt` or, better, its shorthand variant: `+farm.innerHTML + x`.

```
  var x = parseInt(2),
      w = prompt("hunt or farm? dare to fight?");

  if (w === 'farm') {
    var farm = document.getElementById("farm"),
        out = document.getElementById("output"),
        farmValue = Number(farm.innerHTML) + x;

    out.innerHTML = w;
    farm.innerHTML = farmValue;
  };
```

Answer (score 0):

As you have used innerHtml to get the values so I am assuming this is not to be an input element.
    `var farm = document.getElementById("farm").innerHTML;`

If this is the case then make sure the innerHtml you are getting is a number, if yes then the resultant with pasreInt will be a number.
As innerHtml contains html tags as well so you can try with **innerText** instead.
It will always returns text contained inside the element on which can apply parseInt/parseFloat to get the integer part of it.

Hope this helps.